# Angular.js $resouce won't JSONify postData when it's not an object?

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-resource

```
lubanlockServices.factory('UserConfig', ['$resource',
    function($resource){
        return $resource('user/config/:item', {item: '@item'});
    }
]);

lubanlockControllers.controller('NavCtrl', ['$scope', 'UserConfig',
    function($scope, UserConfig){
        $scope.minimized = UserConfig.get({item: 'nav_minimized'});

        $scope.$watch('minimized', function(value){
            console.log(value);
        });

        $scope.toggleMinimize = function(){
            $scope.minimized = !$scope.minimized;
            UserConfig.save({item: 'nav_minimized'}, $scope.minimized);
        }
    }
]);
```

The problem is, when $scope.minimized is false, the request will not contain any post data, rather than sending a JSONified false. That causes problem saving value in server side.

Any solution? Or is there something wrong with my usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is Javascript *Object* Notation, you really should be POSTing (and retrieving) an object.  Ideally, it would look like:

```
$scope.config = UserConfig.get({item: 'nav_minimized'}); 
//returns a $resource with data {minimized: false}

$scope.$watch('config.minimized', function(value){
    console.log(value);
});
$scope.toggleMinimize = function(){
    $scope.config.minimized = !$scope.config.minimized;
    $scope.config.$save(); //and then you can do this to save
}
```